# SAPUI5 formatter not working inside a fragment

Tags: xml, sapui5

I have a XML fragment where i need to use a formatter. But the fragment does not recognize the formatter

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" controllerName="dol.ui.model.formatter">
    <l:Grid defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12" width="auto">
        <l:content>
            <f:SimpleForm title="Section 1" columnsL="2" columnsM="2" editable="false" emptySpanL="0" emptySpanM="0" labelSpanL="4" labelSpanM="4" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" maxContainerCols="2" minWidth="1024">
                <f:content>
                    <core:Title text="Sub Section 1.1" />
                    <Label text="G/L Account" />
                    <Text text="{path: 'GLACC', formatter: '.formatter.removeLeadingZeros'}" />
                </f:content>
            </f:SimpleForm>
        </l:content>
    </l:Grid>
</core:FragmentDefinition>
```

And the formatter is

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";
    return {
        removeLeadingZeros: function(sString) {
            console.log(Number(sString).toString());
            return Number(sString).toString();

        }
    };
});
```

The fragment is inserted from a view which has controller defined. A similair formatting is working which is used in the view. but the same is not working in the fragment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Methods assigned in XML fragment not triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64534777/methods-assigned-in-xml-fragment-not-triggered)

Answer (score 1):

How do you instantiate the Fragment? Programmatically (e.g. calling sap.ui.xmlfragment(...))? Then give the View's controller as additional parameter to the Fragment - it does not have access to the View's controller by default and therefore the formatter function cannot be found.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample call, how to pass the controller.

Comment: @FrancescoIannazzo and for future readers: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045

Answer (score 1):

Use **`this`** attribute in the function when you call the fragment, and it will take the parent view formatter by default:

`var oFragment = sap.ui.xmlfragment("YourFragment.xml",this);`

Comment: outdated, nowadays fragments are bound via, Fragment.load() https://ui5.sap.com/1.62.0/#/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment/methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load

Comment: @Erch For the latest APIs, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep your fragment independent(not dependent on the controller) this approach works for me:

1. In some file define the formatter as follows:

   ```
   jQuery.sap.declare("yourApp.fragment.someModel.Formatter");

   yourApp.fragment.someModel.Formatter = {
       trim: function(sStr) {
           return str && sStr.trim();
       }};
   ```
2. Now you can use it anywhere this way:

   ```
   <Text text="{path: 'GLACC', formatter:'yourApp.fragment.someModel.Formatter.trim'}" />
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you write like below in the controller it should recognize the formatter

```
sap.ui.define([
//formatter path to call formatter.js file. see example below
"path/models/formatter",
], function(formatter){
    "use strict";
    return {
formatter: formatter,

    };
});
```

Define the formatter function in formatter.js file wherever you want to place it

```
removeLeadingZeros: function(sString) {
                console.log(Number(sString).toString());
                return Number(sString).toString();

            }
```

see ex. for formatter.js file

```
sap.ui.define([], function() {
    "use strict";

    return {
removeLeadingZeros: function(sString) {
                    console.log(Number(sString).toString());
                    return Number(sString).toString();

                }

} });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the View Controller to the Fragment Object, so it worked for me:

```
    sap.ui.define([
    ...
    "com/example/test/model/formatter"
], function (..., formatter) {
    "use strict";
    return Controller.extend("com.example.test.controller.Controller1", {
        formatter: formatter,
...

changeFragment: function {
    oFragment = Fragment.load({
                        id: oView.getId(),
                        name: "com.example.test.view.Fragment1",
                        controller: this
});
```

Comment: As explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the fragment definition:

```xml
<core:FragmentDefinition ... controllerName="dol.ui.model.formatter">
```

**controllerName** is pointing to the formatter file itself but it is not a controller because it don't extend from **Controller**.

Solution:

Pass the controller of the parent view where formatter property is defined

```js
formater: formatter
```

or create a controller for that fragment