# Methods assigned in XML fragment not triggered

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'd like to attach a `liveChange` event to the `Input` field of the reusable `Fragment`-based `Dialog` ([Walkthrough Step 19: Reuse Dialogs](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/19453962b8074b7399372c65cbe05370)).

In XML-template `HelloDialog.fragment.xml` I've added:

```xml
<Input
    id = "input-b"
    type = "Password"
    liveChange = ".onLiveChange"
    placeholder = "Enter your password" />
```

In the fragment's controller `HelloDialog.js` I've added:

```js
onLiveChange: function (oEvent) {
    const sNewValue = oEvent.getParameter("value");
    this.byId("getValue").setText(sNewValue);
    console.log("sNewValue");
}
```

Then I set in DevTools a break point in this method and try to type a text in the relevant `Input` and expect that the break point will be fired but nothing happens.

I've tried to add `onLiveChange` into the view's controller from where I call this fragment and to the `Component.js` as well, but still no reaction.

Why `onLiveChange` is not triggered in my case? In SAP [Sample: Input - Value Update](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/entity/sap.m.Input/sample/sap.m.sample.InputValueUpdate) everything is OK, but they use a regular view, not a fragment-based dialog.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to enable triggering event handlers that are assigned in the fragment definition, a controller instance (or a plain object containing the handlers) should be passed when calling the API that **creates** the fragment.

Given `this` as a reference to the current controller instance:

### Since UI5 1.93: [`Controller#loadFragment`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/loadFragment) (Recommended)

```js
this.loadFragment({ name: "my.Fragment" }); // See API reference for more options
```

In the above API, the `id` and `controller` are `this.getView().getId()` and `this` **by default** respectively. And as a bonus, the loaded fragment is added to the `<dependents>` aggregation of the view automatically as well (unless `addToDependents: false`). The created ManagedObject also contains the *[owner ID](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/sap.ui.core.Component.getOwnerIdFor)* with which the framework can apply any existing extension — no need to wrap `loadFragment` with `sap.ui.core.Component#runAsOwner` explicitly.

---

### For older UI5 versions or if the controller is not accessible

⚠️ To enable extensions, the below APIs **must** be wrapped with [`Component#runAsOwner`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Component#methods/runAsOwner).

#### Since UI5 1.58: [`Fragment.load`](https://sdk.openui5.org/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment#methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load)

```js
// Fragment required from "sap/ui/core/Fragment"
this.getOwnerComponent().runAsOwner(() => Fragment.load({
  id: this.getView().getId(),
  name: "my.Fragment",
  controller: this, // or a plain object that contains the event handlers
}));
```

#### UI5 1.56 and below: <del>`sap.ui.xmlfragment`</del> (Deprecated)

```js
sap.ui.xmlfragment(this.getView().getId(), "my.Fragment", this); // Deprecated!
```

---

Related documentation topic: [Instantiation of Fragments](https://sdk.openui5.org/topic/04129b2798c447368f4c8922c3c33cd7)