# Loading the UI5 fragments

Tags: sapui5

In the official UI5 documentation, there is a code snippet how to load a `sap.ui.core.Fragment`:

```js
sap.ui.require(["sap/ui/core/Fragment"], async function(Fragment){
    this.myFragment = await Fragment.load({
        name: "my.useful.VerySimpleUiPart"
    });
});
```

At the same time, I can load a `sap.ui.core.Fragment` using a [`loadFragment`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller#methods/loadFragment) of `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`:

```js
this.myFragment = await this.loadFragment({
    name: "my.useful.VerySimpleUiPart"
});
```

`this` is an instance of a `BaseController` based on `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`.

As far as I understand, `loadFragment` uses `sap.ui.core.Fragment.load` under the hood:

> *Loads a Fragment by [`sap.ui.core.Fragment.load`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/api/sap.ui.core.Fragment#methods/sap.ui.core.Fragment.load).*

If so, why do we need `Controller.loadFragment` at all? Is there any official SAP advice which approach to use?

Comment: The advantages of `loadFragment` are also highlighted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64541325/5846045. Generally, it reduces the application code since the new API takes care of adding the fragment to the `<dependents>` aggregation, assigning the event listener, prefixing ID, etc. by default.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fragment loading evolves as new versions get published:

Before: 1.58:

```
sap.ui.xmlfragment Deprecated as of version 1.58. use sap.ui.core.Fragment.load instead
```

Since: 1.58:

```
sap.ui.core.Fragment.load
```

Since: 1.93:

```
sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.loadFragment
```

So the recommended approach depends on your UI5 version.

The recommendation for the latest version (1.95) is in the [Instantiation of Fragments](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/04129b2798c447368f4c8922c3c33cd7) section of SAPUI5 SDK.

Comment: The article, a link you provided to, contains a list of advantages of using `loadFragment` over `Fragment.load`.